# How can I make a note in a Kindle book in Kindle for Mac?

Tags: kindle

On the Amazon site, it says:

> Click on any word or click and drag over a passage to create a highlight or add a note within a book. Once you've selected text, a pop-up box gives you the option to Highlight, Add Note, Copy, or the More dropdown menu.

But that doesn't seem to work in the Kindle application I have on my Mac.

Is there a way to add a note in a book in Kindle for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the latest version (1.8.1 as of this writing) directly from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_mac_ln_ar?docId=1000464931), the updater doesn't seem to pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was moments from posting

> "I also have the same question.
>    I have just downloaded the latest version, so it can't be that reason..."

...then I figured out the problem in my case:

Even though I was viewing text, it was in a graphic. 
Text in the book worked just fine. 
It was the graphic that didn't let me annotate.

Best of luck!